# Delete workflow menu entry

Tags: workflow, share, alfresco

I installed Alfresco Community v3.4.0, and I'm trying to customise the workflow in the Share client. What I would like to do is to the delete all entries in the workflow menu, in order to leave only the "Review and Approve Workflow". I'm not very proficient in java but I tried to edit the file share-workflow-form-config.xml, to no avail. I installed alfresco locally on my machine and I suppose I have to stop and then restart the virtual server, but not luck with that either. Can someone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to modify file: \Alfresco\tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\web-extension\share-config-custom.xml

add this :

```
    <alfresco-config>
    <config evaluator="string-compare" condition="Workflow">
    <hidden-workflows>
        <workflow name="activiti$activitiReviewPooled"/>
        <!-- leave Review and Approve workflow definition <workflow name="activiti$activitiReview"/> -->
        <workflow name="activiti$activitiAdhoc"/>
        <workflow name="activiti$activitiParallelReview"/>
        <workflow name="activiti$activitiParallelGroupReview"/>
    </hidden-workflows>
    </config>
</alfresco-config>
```

Comment: I tried this but its doesn't hide any workflow from the menu.

Answer (score 2):

Log in to the workflow console:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco/faces/jsp/admin/workflow-console.jsp
```

Then, type "show definitions all" and hit Submit. You'll see the workflow definitions that have been deployed.

What you are looking for is the workflow definition ID. For example, on my machine, one of them looks like this: "activiti$activitiAdhoc:1:4".

So for each workflow you want to undeploy, execute "undeploy definition activiti$activitiAdhoc:1:4".

Be careful. When you undeploy a definition that has a running workflow instance the workflows will be terminated.

If you get stuck, type "help" and click "Submit".

The next time you restart Alfresco, the workflows may get re-deployed. If you don't want that to happen, either edit the Spring config to set auto deploy to false or use the hidden approach the other poster suggested.